# Does Spring flush objects to disk under load?

Tags: java, spring, serialization, sonarqube

SonarQube created an issue in our code base: squid:S1948.

> Fields in a Serializable class must themselves be either Serializable or transient even if the class is never explicitly serialized or deserialized. That's because under load, most J2EE application frameworks flush objects to disk, and an allegedly Serializable object with non-transient, non-serializable data members could cause program crashes, and open the door to attackers.

Is that also the case for Spring?

We are using `javax.json.JsonObject` which isn't implementing `Serializable` and to resolve this issue we would need to create some ugly `readObject` and `writeObject` methods even though we never serialize that class ourselves.

Comment: Can you make the containing class non-serializable to stop this warning?

Comment: No, Spring does not flush objects to disk. Could you post a minimal example to show what triggers the problem?

Comment: Isn't this really a question of what the web server does rather than of what Spring does?